# How to internationalize of HTML text non-programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, internationalization

I need to refactor my appliation to make it support internationalization.

I found https://github.com/jquery-i18n-properties/jquery-i18n-properties, but it seems to only support programmaticallytranslating the text using jQuery.

But there are huge hard-coded text in my JSP/html files, so I hope to find a way that **ALSO** supports internationalize the static html text like:

```
<title>@{title_here}<title>
<div>@{label}</div>
```

and the page will automatically replace these values into the correct one after I read the correct properties files, without setting every text using jquery like $(....).text(read_from_properties);

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro, yes, sorry for the typo

Comment: I don't know if there's a real non-programmatically solution for this. As you say, HTML is static, so there will always have to be some code/program under the hood doing the trick and replacing the values

Comment: I am unsure if this question is a good fit for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Since html is static, you can't just throw it a data file and expect it to pump out the right language.

If you have hard-coded texts in your JSP files, I'd implement i18n on the server side.

If you have a single-page app, you'll probably use some template engine (as part of a MV* framework, or stand-alone) to render the html. I have used [polyglot](http://airbnb.github.io/polyglot.js/) in the past to good effect.

Whichever way, you will need to change all your current static texts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's exactly what you are looking for, but the first thing that came into my mind when I saw what you wanted was [handlebars expressions](http://handlebarsjs.com/):

```
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div>{{welcome}}</div>
    <div>{{name}}</div>
    <div>{{time}}</div>
</script>
<div id="generated"></div>
```

You'd still need a little code to change the language from one to another, but nothing really difficult. You can see an example running here: http://jsfiddle.net/gj9hbhwj/1/

```
function changeLanguage(lang) {
    var templateSource = document.getElementById('myTemplate').innerHTML;
    var template = Handlebars.compile(templateSource);
    var generatedHolder = document.getElementById('generated');
    generatedHolder.innerHTML = template(int[lang]);
}
```

---

On personal and small projects/apps, I use a simple jQuery/JSON combination that takes just a few lines of code and works like a charm:

```
/** ON A SEPARATE FILE **/
int = {
    "en": {
        "#welcome": "Welcome to my site",
        "#name": "My name is...",
        "#time": "It's 8 o'clock"
    },
    "es": {
        "#welcome": "Bienvenido a mi web",
        "#name": "Mi nombre es...",
        "#time": "Son las 8 en punto"
    }
}

/** ON MAIN SCRIPT **/
function changeLanguage(target_lang) {
    if (int[target_lang]) {
        $.each(int[target_lang], function (index, value) {
            $(index).text(value);
        });
    }
}
```

The keys are the CSS selectors of the elements I want to modify, and the value is the text in the different languages. Using `$.each()` I get all the strings modified in no time and just 3 lines of code (independently of the number of phrases to replace). You can see it running here: http://jsfiddle.net/4y5j0gr7/